# php namespaces & autoload

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I've read some posts about namespaces and autoload in php 5.3+, but still haven't succeeded in creating one working :x maybe some of you have an idea of what's going wrong about my code ?
Thank you previously.

**Autoloader.php** *class*

```
<?php

    namespace my;

    class AutoLoader {

        private $aExt;
        private $sPath;
        protected static $instance;

        public static function getInstance() {
            if(!self::$instance instanceof self ) {
                self::$instance = new self();
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }

        function __construct($sPath = __DIR__, $exts = 'php') {
            // define path and extensions to include
            $this->setPath($sPath);
            $this->setExtensions($exts);
        }

        public function getPath() {
            return $this->sPath;
        }

        public function setPath($path){
            $this->sPath = $path;
        }

        public function removePath() {
            unset ($this->sPath);
        }

        public function addExtension($ext) {
            // prepends period to extension if none found
            $this->aExt[$ext]   = (substr($ext, 0, 1) !== '.') ? '.'.$ext : $ext;
        }

        public function removeExtension($ext) {
            unset ($this->aExt[$ext]);
        }

        public function getExtensions() {
            return $this->aExt;
        }

        public function setExtensions($extensions) {
            // convert
            if (is_string($extensions)) {
                $extensions = array($extensions);
            }

            // add
            foreach($extensions as $ext) {
                $this->addExtension($ext);
            }
        }

        public function register() {
            set_include_path($this->sPath);
            // comma-delimited list of valid source-file extensions
            spl_autoload_extensions(implode(',',$this->aExt));
            // default behavior without callback
            spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'autoload'));
        }


            public function autoload($sClassName) {
            include_once($sClassName.'.php');
            return;
        }

    }

    $autoloader = new AutoLoader();
    $autoloader->register();
?>
```

**MyClass.php** *the class i am trying to load dinamically*

```
<?php

    namespace my\tools;

    class MyClass {

        function __construct() {}

        function __destruct() {}

        function test() {
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }

?>
```

**index.php** *the caller*

```
<?php

    include_once('../Libraries/php/my/AutoLoader.php');

    new my\tools\MyClass();
?>
```

**and finally the class structures on my disk**

```
Libraries
  |_php
     |_my
     | |_Autoloader.php
     |
     |_MyClass.php
```

Comment: sorry i didn't find how to edit my post, what I'd like to do with the autoloader, it's to include only include_once('../Libraries/php/my/AutoLoader.php'); at the beginning of every script I write, and then autoload of course :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a little on PHP.net website, the solution were really simple :/

In fact php autoload function MUST be on root namespace /, mine was on first level of my package (my/), when i moved the class to root namespace everything worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

That's a tad bit over-engineered, my friend.

You might want to take a look at simply using [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) (PRS-0 is now depreciated,  [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) is the new one), an autoloader specification from a large number of PHP projects, like phpBB, Joomla, CakePHP, Zend Framework [and lots more](http://groups.google.com/group/php-standards/web/voting-projects-members).  It's built with namespaces in mind, but works well with or without them.

The advantage of PSR-0 (or PSR-4) is that it leads to a clean, simple, obvious directory structure that an increasing number of projects are supporting.  This means using *one* autoloader instead of a single autoloader for every single set of code.

Comment: i'll take a look to it :) I usually use more simplistic autoloader (I work on php 5.2.n at work) and while trying differents setups for personal project i found this utilisation of autoloader that seemed interesting :)

Comment: Charles, I fixed a broken link (PSR0) and added info about new PSR4, the other link is also broken (link text "and lots more") but couldn't find a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

`spl_autoload_register()` expects a valid callback. You give ... something ^^ But not a callback. A callback is

```
// a closure
$cb = function ($classname) { /* load class */ }
// object method
$cb = array($object, 'methodName');
// static class method
$cb = array('className', 'methodName');
// function
$cb = 'functionName';
```

See [manual: spl_autoload_register()](http://php.net/spl-autoload-register) for further information and examples.

Comment: I know how callbacks works :) but if you do not specify a valid callback for spl_autoload_register() method, (from php doc) "The autoload function being registered. If no parameter is provided, then the default implementation of spl_autoload() will be registered." SO I maybe have misunderstood the description but won't php automatically load the class if callback is omitted?

Comment: @aoi-onore: "If no parameter is provided", right, but you provide a parameter. PHP will only register a builtin loader (that should then autoload classes). However: Call `spl_autoload_register()` without arguments or `spl_autoload_register('spl_autoload')`, if you want to use the default one. But why do you write your own one, if you dont want to use it? :?

Comment: I dont see an error. And of course an external autoload-system cannot call private methods too.

Comment: I edited my answer while you were commenting i guess, I tried to put the autoloader function in public but the result is the same :/